# Как установить GMP на Win 7 Visual Studio 15

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015

Добрый день
Как установить GMP (gmplib.org) на Win 7 как библиотеку по умолчанию в Visual Studio 2015
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multi-Precision_Library

Answer (score 0):

мне действительно помогло вот это исчерпывающее описание, я все скомпилировал и теперь имею библиотеку GMP, а также документация GMP.
[Мануал по установке](https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-discuss/2013-July/005384.html)

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните ответ основным из ссылки. Ответы содержащие только ссылку обычно удаляются.